# the first line has 5 words , the second line has 4 words and third line has 2 words. So how can i count them using python

Tags: python, spyder

example :

```
dam | luru | Goal | Limaste | Querto
elh | Dub | Lon row | Mumb
lhi | mba
```

I want to count the number of characters in each row. for eg. the first row has 5 characters.
please help.

Comment: Please clarify your question: In title you ask to "replace pipe with space"; in question body you ask to "count characters". Also how does first row contain 5 characters, can you give an example what you mean by that?

Comment: the first row is : dam | luru | Goal | Limaste | Querto                                       so the there are 5 words i.e , dam,luru,Goal,Limaste,Querto. so i want to know how to count them using R or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the pipes and replace them with a space in Python:

```
string = "dam | luru | Goal | Limaste | Querto elh | Dub | Lon row | Mumb lhi | mba"
string.replace('|',' ')
```

If you want to count the number of characters (in python):

```
string = "dam | luru | Goal | Limaste | Querto elh | Dub | Lon row | Mumb lhi | mba"
parts = string.split('|')
for part in parts:
    print(len(part)+1) #+1 because the | character itself will be removed
```

**Edit:**

As per the recent edit, you want to count the number of pipe separated terms in each line when multiple lines of input are present. To do that for one line, you can simply do:

```
parts = line.split('|')
print(len(parts))
```

where the line variable contains one line of input.

Comment: This is the error i am getting .Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: dam | luru | Goal | Limaste | Querto        -      5
elh | Dub | Lon row | Mumb                     -      4 
lhi | mba                                                   -      1                                                 This is my desired output. As you can see dam | luru | Goal | Limaste | Querto are 5 words so i want output on the side as 5.